# Happiness Index

Tags: society, indicators

I found that Bhutan created the [Gross National Happiness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gross_National_Happiness) (GNH) Index in order to evaluate the happiness of their citizens and compare that with other countries. I presume the intention of that was to do some comparative politics and be able to find out the output in terms of happiness of specific policies.

Even though, when one analyzes GNH quickly realizes it's a really subjective index. And that's not surprising at all, since happiness is something indeed pretty subjective.

Even though, I was interested if some institutions of any kind (with international repercussion) had created similar indexes, that try to find out some value of happiness in a country.

*I'm aware of the existence of the [Human Development Index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_Development_Index), though I wouldn't say it falls upon the consideration of "happiness index"*

Comment: "I pressume the intention of that was to do some Compared Politics" - may be i'm being too cynical, but I'm guessing the intention of that is to find a way to show the populace how good things are in the country and thus get support for the government...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know that the Bhutan index is derived from work for the "[World Happiness Report](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Happiness_Report)"?

There is also the [Gallup-Healthways Global Well-Being Index](https://www.livescience.com/47863-countries-happiness-rank.html) that ranks based on how people fare primarily on five factors: Having purpose, physical health, financial security, having supportive social relationships, and being satisfied with the community.

Comment: Agreed that measuring happiness is a vague idea. Hell, in some countries being disconnected from politics might radically improve actual citizen contentment if you subscribe to the "ignorance is bliss" notion. And sometimes I think it might be true. Also found that the OECD is trying a similar measurement at: http://www.oecdbetterlifeindex.org